# how do i import everything from another python script using imp

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my run.py file:

```
import imp
import os

for script in os.listdir("MyFolder"):
    if os.path.isdir("MyFolder/" + script) == False and script.endswith(".py"):
        script = imp.load_dynamic(script[:-3], f"MyFolder/{script}")

print(script.multiply(2,6))
```

then this is MyFolder/example.py file:

```
def multiply(x:int, y:int):
    return x * y
```

this already works but how whould i do from example.py import * except with imp
so this could work:

```
import imp
import os

for script in os.listdir("MyFolder"):
    if os.path.isdir("MyFolder/" + script) == False and script.endswith(".py"):
        imp.load_dynamic(script[:-3], f"MyFolder/{script}")

print(multiply(2,6))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `imp` module is deprecated in favor of `importlib`.

Instead of making the name of dynamic module follow the name of the script, if you set it to something constant things become a little easier. e.g.

```
import importlib.util
import os
import sys

for script in os.listdir("MyFolder"):
    script_path = os.path.join("MyFolder", script)
    if not os.path.isdir(script_path) and script_path.endswith(".py"):
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("example", script_path)
        sys.modules["example"] = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.load_module("example")

        from example import *


print(multiply(4, 5))
```